# Let $u$ be a harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\int_\mathbb{R} |u|^p < \infty$. Then $u \equiv 0$.

Tags: harmonic-functions

This post [Let $u$ harmonic. Then $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|u|^2<\infty \implies u=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076250/let-u-harmonic-then-int-mathbb-rdu2-infty-implies-u-0) answers this question in the case when $p=2$ using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and an application of the Mean-Value Property. Since Cauchy-Schwarz only works for $p=2$, I was wondering if there is a generalization for $p \geq 2$. I tried it using Holder's Inequality, but I was not able to make that work.

Comment: Holder would seem to give it directly for $1 < p < \infty.$  Where did you have a problem applying Holder to it?

Comment: Here is my specific problem: When I try to apply Holder, I can't seem to get $|u|^p$ inside the integral by itself, so I can't apply the assumption $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^p < \infty$. Since $||u||_1 \leq ||u||_p||u||_q$ by Holder, I always get two integrals --- $(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u|^p)^{1/p}$ and $(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u|^q)^{1/q}$ --- and I don't know how to work with the integral involving the conjugate exponent $q$.

Comment: The statement of Holder should be $\|fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q.$  If you understand what was done in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the post you linked, they set $$f = u, \qquad g = \mathbf{1}_{B(x,r)}$$ Do the same thing with Holder.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to normalize $g=1_{B(x,r)}$, so $\frac{1}{|B(r,x)|^{1/q}}||1_{B(x,r)}||^{1/q}=1$ and the answer falls right out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apply Hölder for $u$ and $1$ over $B(x,r)$.